# Free iPhone like controls for .NET CF

Tags: .net, vb.net, mobile, user-interface

I'm developing a mobile project that I really want to look good. I love the way the iPhone controls look and I'm wondering if anyone knows of any free UI components that can help me make my app look more like the iPhone? Specifically, I'm really wanting a GREAT looking listbox.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It is probably worth looking at Silverlight Mobile which replaces System.Windows.Forms in v7 (due later this year, I believe) - it also has an extensive style guide available.

Comment: If you exclusively look for free components then your UI is going to look like it was made from free components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you'd go with copyright infringement but you could build some interface components from the vector graphics found [here](http://www.mercuryintermedia.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/iphone-ui-vector-elements).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are after but these guys made a nice project that feels like iphone 
...well sometimes :)

but relly... its a nice project and maybe you will find what you are looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/iui/

Good luck